If $M_n(R)$ is unital then $R$ is unital
I was given the question that

If $R$ is unital then so is $M_n(R)$

Consider the diagonal scalar matrix with diagonal entries $1_R$. This clearly works as identity.
However, is it true that if $M_n(R)$ is unital then $R$ is unital?

Usually we call a ring with unity a unitary ring.

Denote by $I$ your identity. Then, for $x\in R$ set $M_x$ the matrix with only one non null coefficient in $1,1$ being $x$. Then you know that $M_x I=M_x$ and $IM_x=M_x$. Denote by $e$ the $1,1$ coefficient of $I$. You have $xe=x$ and $ex=x$ so $R$ is unital.
